# Solve congruence eq's with large exponents

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

My problem is:

Find all solutions of the set

$$x \equiv 2^{191889} \, \mathrm{mod} \, 119$$
$$x \equiv 2^{119} \, \mathrm{mod} \, 19.$$

If the numbers on the right hand side where not large, I would use the chineese remainder theorem to solve the problem. So the problem is really how to compute $2^{191889} \, \mathrm{mod} \, 119$ (and $2^{119} \, \mathrm{mod} \, 19$).

I looked for a similar question, but they seemed to use the method of computing $2^2, 2^4, 2^8, 2^{16},$ and so on. Where you finally multiply the terms you need to get $2^{191889}$. But this seems infeasible for the very large exponent in the first equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: $119 = 7 \times 17$, $2^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ and ...

Comment: And 2^8 is congruent to 1 mod 17, and then we can quickly get there! Thanks!